# Can ${2n \choose n}$ ever be divisble by $2n+1$ (for positive integer $n$)?

Tags: nt.number-theory, enumerative-combinatorics

The question in the title arose from some semi-recreational number theory. A quick check on a spreadsheet shows the answer is negative for $1\leq n \leq 20$; I haven't tried to use any more serious computational tools.

Since ${2n \choose n}=(n+1)C_n$ where $C_n$ is the $n$th Catalan number, and since $n+1$ and $2n+1$ are coprime for $n\geq 1$, the question in the title is equivalent to asking if $C_n$ is ever divisible by $2n+1$.

One naive idea, which I haven't been able to make work, is to find some function $f:{\mathbb N}\to {\mathbb N}$ such that $f(n)$ is never divisible by $2n+1$ while $C_n+f(n)$ is always divisible by $2n+1$, using some kind of bijective/enumerative proof. However, looking at $C_n \bmod 2n+1$ doesn't indicate any obvious patterns to me.

Comment: Yes, try $n=97$.

Comment: Hah! Thank you @MattF. With hindsight: was this a matter of looking at the prime factorization of $2n+1$ and then checking how often the prime factors occur in the ranges $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $\{1,\dots 2n\}$?

Comment: Sort of -- it obviously won't work if $2n+1$ is prime, so I looked at $n$ with $2n+1=(2i+1)(2j+1)$ for small $i,j$.

Comment: Heuristically I think one would expect that for any integers $a, b$ with $a > 0$ then infinitely often $a n + b$ should divide $\binom{2 n}{n}$, since for most $n$ the number $a n + b$ has only small prime factors with a not too large exponent, and $\binom{2 n}{n}$ is for most $n$ divisible by most small primes. I'm not sure whether this can be turned into a proof.

Comment: The relevant entry in the OEIS is https://oeis.org/A073076 .

Comment: Thank you @OfirGorodetsky !

Comment: This recent paper of Ford and Konyagin might be relevant in studying the infinitude of $n$s for which the divisibility holds: https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.03903 .

Comment: Divisibility holds 5906 times for values of $n$ up to $10^5$.